# Localization of a Gaussian

Tags: filters, gaussian

Studying for an exam I'll have I ran into a question about computing the localization of a Gaussian Filter in 1D, but sadly I have no idea of what such localization is. Can you give me a hint?

Thanks

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot or something?

Comment: For what? It is a general term question, so for a *generic* Gaussian, what's its localization?

Comment: Localization is definitely not a standard term. It's sometimes used to mean the width of a filter, but a Gaussian filter (theoretically at least) has infinite width. Are you using a specific textbook that talks about that?

Comment: @Phonon Nope no textbook, can it be the "significant" width? I know that at some point the Gaussian filter get close to 0 (even if never 0). How can it be determined such thing with a Gaussian? Generally how the width is related to the parameter I have? (std dev.)